# Searchable Vue-Multiselect inside x-template script tag

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I'm working with php and vue trying to insert a vue-multiselect inside an x-template script tag sort of like below.  I just want to know how one inserts an imported vue component inside an x-template tag or if it can be done, or if the  tag needs to be used instead:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="questions-template">
<multiselect></multiselect>
</script>
```